# Contrast Media for Plant cells

Tags: cell-biology, microscopy

I currently have a waterweed (elodea) preparation for my optical microscope but i can only see some of the structures (membrane, wall, chloroplasts and the nucleus).

Now I want to see more (Like the Vacuole, Peroxisome, Mitochondria, Amyloplast, Ribosome, Golgi Apparatus, and endoplasmatic reticulum if possible with an optical microscope)

I know there are contrast media like the lugol's iodine solution (iodine-potassium iodide solution) but what will it show? And are there more?

Thanks in advance